Mongoose.save() doesn't seem to actually change anything in the database
I'm trying to update an object within an array in a MongoDB database. I don't seem to be getting very far with Googling the problem, and Mongo doesn't seem to be coming back with any errors so I'm a bit stuck.
Here's my code:
const { SnagList } = require("../models/schemaModel.js");
//get the details of the snag update from the request object, get the relevant customer from the database, loop through the snags array and update with the new info we just received in the request
const snagUpdate = async (req, res) => {
  const snagId = req.body.update.id;
  const snagLocation = req.body.update.location;
  const snagDescription = req.body.update.snagDetails;
  try {
    const list = await SnagList.findById(req.body.customerId);

    list.snags.forEach((snag) => {
      if (snag.id === snagId) {
        snag.location = snagLocation;
        snag.snagDetails = snagDescription;
      }
    });

    await list.save();

    res.send("Snag update processed");
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
    res.send("Error during update process");
  }
};

module.exports = snagUpdate;

so what I'm trying to do is retrieve a 'snaglist' by ID, then loop through the list and make the modifications, then save it. When I save using save(), it seems to perform the operation because it doesn't return any errors. The problem is that when I check the DB for the update, it hasn't actually done anything.
If it helps solve anything, I tried to .push a new object to the list array and it seems to work fine. The mongoose docs don't seem to mention anything about issues like this as far as I'm aware.

Post your schema for SnagList. Mongodb let's you find an element(s) from within an array and update it all in one query. There is no need to perform forEach looping as it is inefficient and blocks the event loop in Node.js so you really want to avoid that. You have a snagId so it should be very simple once you post your schema.

@jQueeny
Thanks for comment. I was eventually able to get this working using this code:
await SnagList.updateOne(
{ _id: req.body.customerId, "snags.id": snagId },
{
$set: {
"snags.$.location": snagLocation,
"snags.$.snagDetails": snagDescription,
},
}
);
If you'd still like to take a look at it, here's the schema:
{
snagger: "string",
customer: "string",
snags: [],
approved: "string",
notes: "string",
completed: "string",
}

Model.find(), Model.findById(...) etc. in the mongoose module return a promise, not a JavaScript object; hence, it's not directly possible to make any update operation on this promise.
For making any CRUD operation, you have to use the "then-catch" structure:
SnagList
.findById(req.body.customerId)
.then((list) => {
    // Perform your operations here.
}).catch((err) => console.error(err));


Thanks for the answer. I'm actually able to access a Javascript object using const list = await SnagList.findById(req.body.customerId);. The issue I'm having is this doesn't seem to actually save to the database. I'm able to make modifications to the top level items in the document using this exact same method, which makes me think this is something to do with the fact I'm updating the properties of an object within an array.
